# Deleting a node in a Binary Search Tree(BST) is causing seg faults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble with removing a node from my BST and I can't seem to find the culprit to my seg faults. Every other part of my BST I've tested and it runs smoothly. I've also tried deleting nodes with different conditions but it's all the same result.

```
template <typename object>
bool BST<object>::remove(object& data)
{
    if (nodes == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return remove(root_, data);
    }
}



template <typename object>
bool BST<object>::remove(node<object>* current_node_, object& data)
{
    if (current_node_ == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int relation = compare(data, current_node_->get_data());

    //if you need to keep searching right
    if (relation > 0)
    {
        remove(current_node_->get_right(), data);
    }
    else if (relation < 0)
    {
        remove(current_node_->get_left(), data);
    }
    else
    {
        //LEAF CASE
        if (current_node_->is_leaf())
        {
            //root case
            if (compare(root_->get_data(), data) == 0)
            {
                root_ = NULL;
            }

            else
            {
                if (current_node_->is_right_child())
                {
                    current_node_->get_parent()->set_right(NULL);
                }
                else
                {
                    current_node_->get_parent()->set_left(NULL);
                }
            }

            //release from memory
            delete current_node_;
            nodes--;
        }
        //ONE CHILD CASE
        else if (current_node_->has_one_child())
        {
            //root node
            if (compare(root_->get_data(), data) == 0)
            {
                if (current_node_->get_right() != NULL)
                {
                    current_node_->get_right()->set_parent(NULL);
                    root_ = current_node_->get_right();
                }
                else
                {
                    current_node_->get_left()->set_parent(NULL);
                    root_ = current_node_->get_left();
                }
            }

            //node with right child
            else if(current_node_->get_right() != NULL)
            {
                current_node_->get_right()->set_parent(current_node_->get_parent());
                if (current_node_->is_right_child())
                {
                    current_node_->get_parent()->set_right(current_node_->get_right());
                }
                else
                {
                    current_node_->get_parent()->set_left(current_node_->get_right());
                }
            }
            //node with left child
            else
            {
                current_node_->get_left()->set_parent(current_node_->get_parent());
                if (current_node_->is_right_child())
                {
                    current_node_->get_parent()->set_right(current_node_->get_left());
                }
                else
                {
                    current_node_->get_parent()->set_left(current_node_->get_left());
                }
            }

            //release from memory
            delete current_node_;
            nodes--;
        }
        //TWO CHILDREN CASE
        else
        {
            node<object>* temp_node_ = find_min(current_node_->get_right());
            object* temp_object_ = new object(temp_node_->get_data());

            remove(temp_node_, temp_node_->get_data());
            current_node_->set_data(*temp_object_);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename object>
node<object>* BST<object>::find_min(node<object>* current_node_)
{
    if(current_node_->get_left() != NULL)
    {   
        find_min(current_node_->get_left());
    }
    else 
    {
        return current_node_;
    }
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You're calling the `remove` function recursively, but don't return what the recursive call returns.

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
current_node_=NULL;
```

After each line

```
delete current_node_;
```

in remove function. Let me inform if its work.

Comment: Didn;t work but I've got it now, thankyou for your help!